# How to remove pixel errors when using TabHost

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

We have a strange problem concerning a TabHost-widget in Android. How can we fix the pixel-Line error (shown on the image below):

[image: Pixel error]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please share your code that creates the tabs. Are you using your own divider drawables?

Comment: have you seen my answer ?

Comment: Have you try My code? What is the result ???

Comment: Hello. Now we know, that it is a bug concerning the standard tabs on Samsung devices. So we definitely can close this issue for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I have three tabs and a custom divider, however a custom xml (customtabview.xml) is used for all five tabs.

Tabs.java

```
    tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; 

    LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customtabview,     null));

    //FIRST TAB 
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("FIRST");
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable .tab_back,0,0 );
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator(v).setContent(R.id.tab_first_info);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //SECOND TAB
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("SECOND");
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.tab_back,0,0 );
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator(v).setContent(R.id.tab_second_info);
     tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //THIRD TAB
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("THIRD");
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.tab_back,0,0 );
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("third").setIndicator(v).setContent(R.id.tab_third_info);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

customtabview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/title"
           android:drawablePadding="4dp"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have Same problem before some days. But now got solution with changing it to images.
By Default First Tab is selected and when the Tab Getting change the all tab get changed automatically  based on the Tab Selection.

See below Code:

```
   public class MainTabActivity extends TabActivity {
    TabHost mTabHost;
    TabWidget mTabWidget;
    private TextView title;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_tab_layout);

        //Resources res = getResources();
        mTabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        mTabWidget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent().setClass(MainTabActivity.this, TodaysDealsGroupActivity.class);
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_todays_deal)).setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_todays_deal), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_loyalshop_selector)).setContent(intent);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(MainTabActivity.this, BuddiesGroupActivity.class);
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_buddies)).setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_buddies), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_buddies_selector)).setContent(intent);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(MainTabActivity.this, SearchGroupActivity.class);
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_search)).setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_search), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_search_selector)).setContent(intent);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(MainTabActivity.this, ProfileGroupActivity.class);
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_profile)).setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_profile), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_profile_selector)).setContent(intent);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(MainTabActivity.this, NotificationsGroupActivity.class);
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_notifications)).setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_notifications), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_notification_selector)).setContent(intent);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);

        for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_black_bg));
            title = (TextView) mTabWidget.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            title.setTextSize(10);
        }

        // check if App starts from the Notification click or not
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("notification")){
            // for the current tab selection
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_blue_bg));
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(4);
            title = (TextView) mTabWidget.getChildAt(4).findViewById(android.R.id.title);

        }else{
            // for the current tab selection
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_blue_bg));
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            title = (TextView) mTabWidget.getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title);

        }


        title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        title.setTextSize(10);

        // listener for the tab changed
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

                for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_black_bg));
                    title = (TextView) mTabWidget.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
                    title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    title.setTextSize(10);
                }

                int tab = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();

                mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tab).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_blue_bg));
                title = (TextView) mTabWidget.getChildAt(tab).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
                title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                title.setTextSize(10);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the XMl file **main_tab_layout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TabHost
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:tabStripEnabled="false" >
            </TabWidget>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Just Replace with your images and See the Result.

Hope this will help you a lot as it help me.

Enjoy Coding...